# GroupBox Custom Control DataBinding

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

Good Day,

I am trying to make a custom control where a property can be bound to a DataSource. I have been searching all day and managed to figure out how to set the custom control DataSource to the desired DataSource on my form. I also saw how to set the values of a ComboBox. But I will be using a GroupBox.

For example, in a ComboBox control we have the properties - DataSource, DisplayMember and Value Member. And the value of the column can be found with "NormalComboBox.SelectedValue".

How will I be able to bind my custom "ValueMember" property to a column in my binding source in order to get the value of the column in the current row?

```
public class ValueGroupBox : GroupBox
    {
        private object _dataSource;

        // ** This is where I am having issues - Need to return value
        private string _valueMember;
        private string _selectedValue;

        public string ValueMember { get { return _valueMember; } set { _valueMember = value; }
        public string SelectedValue { get { return _selectedValue; } set { _selectedValue = value; }
        // ** End of having trouble

        [Category("Custom Data")]
        [Description("Indicates the source of data for the GroupBox control.")]
        [TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataSourceConverter, System.Design")]
        [DefaultValue(null)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public object DataSource
        {
            get
            {
                return this._dataSource;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._dataSource != value)
                {
                    this._dataSource = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Create a Windows Forms user control that supports complex data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-complex-data-binding?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: [Create a Windows Forms user control that supports simple data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-simple-data-binding?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: [Create a Windows Forms user control that supports lookup data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-lookup-data-binding?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: this.groupBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", yourBindingSource, "prop", true));